# Where can I find a simple MON .monitor script to monitor if a process is running on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian

I installed MON on my Debian box and I am trying to find additional .monitor script examples on the web without success so far.

What I'd like to achieve is a monitor script that will simply check if a process is still active.

Can anyone guide me into the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own in this direction

```
ps -ef | grep <processName>
```